# Boundary points and isolated points of $\Bbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

My professor asked us to find the boundary points and isolated points of $\Bbb{Q}$; my answer that there is no boundary point or either isolated point for rational numbers set. However the question for confusing me, which asks "to find", means that there exist boundary points and isolated points, and I have to find them. So is there any boundary point or either isolated point for rational numbers set?

Comment: Find boundary points and isolated point of Q as a subset of what set?  The real numbers?  For any rational number, a, there exist infinitely many rational numbers and infinitely many irrational numbers arbitrarily close to a.

Comment: What would you do if someone asked you to find a [jackalope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackalope)?

Comment: @LeeMosher: I guess you wanted to emphasize that some context should be added here like what one means by the terms isolated and boundary.

Comment: No, that was not my intention. Instead, I wanted to emphasize that the request "to find" something does not imply the existence of anything to find (neither in mathematics nor in real life).

Comment: @LeeMosher: thanks for clarification. I was rather puzzled by the word jackalope.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S\subset \Bbb{R}$. A point $x\in S$ is called isolated if it is not a [limit point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) of $S$.
The set $\Bbb{Q}$ is has no isolated points because if $a\in \Bbb{Q}$ and $\epsilon> 0$,
then $(b−\epsilon, b +\epsilon)$ contains infinitely many rational numbers, and so $b$ is a limit
point of $\Bbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb Q$ has no isolated points.

But every real number is a boundary point of $\Bbb{Q}$, because $\partial{\Bbb Q}= \overline{\Bbb{Q}}\smallsetminus \text{int}(\Bbb Q)= \Bbb R\smallsetminus \emptyset=\Bbb R$.